# Wearing New Clothes in Three Weeks

Tags: halacha, clothing, three-weeks

Can one wear new clothes during Three Weeks? Do pajamas and undergarments have the same rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues.  The first is the happiness of wearing fresh clothes.  This applies from Rosh Chodesh until after Tish'a b'Av (specifically 1/2 day on the 10th for Ashkenazim). Shulchan Aruch [551:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=49). Garments meant to absorb sweat are not worn for happiness, but to prevent being uncomfortable.  So the custom is to wear fresh pajamas and undergarments.  I don't know who talks about this for bein hametzarim, but one source is Aruch Hashulchan 389:7

During the three weeks we refrain from making shehechiyanu.  This applies to wearing new clothes which give you great simcha (like a new suit).  Shulchan Aruch [551:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=54).  We usually will not make a shehechiyanu on shirts and pants and certainly not PJs, but shehechiyanu is situation based so ask your rav.

Comment: So essentialy as long as I dont make a Shechiyanu normally it ok?

Comment: You are reffering to rosh Chodesh Av right?

Comment: It's OK for undergarments/socks/PJ's.  Keep in mind that laundering is still forbidden during  the 9 days even for these garments. Yes, the issue is from Rosh Chodesh Av, the start of the "9 days".  Plus, before Rosh Chodesh, all non-shehecheyanu new clothing is fine, too.